# What else is there to do for the halloween event

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've been playing the Guild Wars 2 Halloween event. I've done Act I, II, and III; I have the two books and the 10-slot trick or treat bag. I've done the Mad King Labryinth several times and the areas that the Lunatic Boatman can port me too (Clock tower, Lunatic Inquisition, Reaper's Rumble).

What else is there to do?  Am I missing anything?

Aside from the costumes that can be purchased with gems; are there any other Halloween items I'm missing?

Comment: Pumpkin Carving gives an title - also, check your achievements (under the "special event" section of achievements in your hero panel) for things you haven't done? (Also, eating candy is a monthly achievement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can work on the holiday achievements, if you haven't completed them all. (Emissary, attend the party, and mad king's world are the only ones that can't be completed in act 3, I believe.)
2. You can do Halloween crafting:
   A. Food and tonics
   B. Halloween exotics (very expensive, though)
3. You can trade candy corn to trick-or-treaters in LA for personalized trick-or-treat bags, and try to get an endless tonic or other rare item.
4. You can play costume brawl (this will still be around after the event, but I suspect fewer people will be playing, at least til we get Wintersday costumes.)
5. Wait and see what's in store for act 4.

Also, in addition to the costumes in te gem store, there is a pack of Halloween mini-pets. There is also a fourth pet that can only be obtained by putting the others into the mystic forge.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  I looked at the requirements to get the halloween exotic staff (my char is a necro).  You're right, it is too expensive for my tastes, and I don't really like the skin all that much.

Comment: Mad King's World can be completed. You need to visit: The Labyrinth, The Clocktower, Reaper's Rumble, and Ascent of Madness.